# MySQL error #1064 - Noob

Tags: mysql, data-binding, mysql-error-1064

I keep getting the following error when trying to make one column in a table refference another column in another table.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY (campaignid) REFERENCES campaigns(id)' at line 1
```

In this case I want to have the column "campaignid" in table "pages" refference (= to) column "id" in the table "campaigns.

```
ALTER TABLE pages FOREIGN KEY (campaignid) REFERENCES campaigns(id)
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do your table schemas look like right now?

Comment: Actually looking at it now I think your alter table syntax is wrong. Let me double check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your missing the `ADD` keyword i suppose ([MySQL docu](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html)):

```
ALTER TABLE pages ADD FOREIGN KEY (campaignid) REFERENCES campaigns(id);
```